# CSS specificity: Why isn't CSS specificity weight of 10 or more class selectors greater than 1 id selector?

Tags: css

While going through the css specificity concept, I understood the fact that it is calculated as a 4 parts

```
1) inline (1000)
2) id     (100)
3) class   (10)
4) html elments (1)
```

CSS with the highest rule will be applied to the corresponding element.

I tried the following example

Created more than 10 classes

```
<div class="a1"> ....
     <div class="a13" id="id1"> TEXT COLOR
     </div> ... 
</div>
```

and the css as

```
.a1 .a2 .a3 .a4 .a5 .a6 .a7 .a8 .a9 .a10 .a11 .a12 .a13 {
    color : red;
}
#id1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Now, even though in this case there are 13 classes the weight is 130. Which is greater than the id.

Result -> [JSFiddle CSS specificity](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp9CX/)

Comment: The confusion here is in the difference between inheritance and specificity. You’re assuming that the children of main will inherit the #main color – which they will; unless declared a color. The fact that the parent has a higher specificity doesn’t matter because you haven’t declared the child in the rule selector.

Comment: CSS use heritage. he can have property of his parent but one property of on him is predominant. You can use an id just on one div whereas you can repeat your class. It's normal that the id is more predominante. If the weight system was applied, there would be a lot of repetition. We especially want to save **time**

Comment: There is even a fifth level; well actually in your list -1 (above "inline"): `!important`

Comment: @feeela - This is a question about specificity. `!important` is not part of the specificity rules - it's part of the cascade rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea that you *add* the numbers to get the specificity is actually wrong. The results of the calculation are the same most of the time, but you have found the edge case where it differs.

From the [W3C CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity):

> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

If you follow the example in that page, you find that the specificities of the rules are as follows:

```
.a1 .a2 .a3 .a4 .a5 .a6 .a7 .a8 .a9 .a10 .a11 .a12 .a13    ||    0,0,13,0
#id1                                                       ||    0,1,0,0
```

Looking at the calculation this way, it is obvious that the ID selector wins. Indeed, one ID selector will override any number of class or element selectors. In turn, an inline definition will override ID style.

Comment: Yes, I agree and came into the same conclusion. Thinking ahead, I was wondering, Isn't the weighing pattern somehow misleading? Assigning 10 points to classes and 100 to ids is so unnecessary, isn't it? It should be left at something like "ids will have more weight than classes". Period.

Comment: @ajc The pattern works in a system with "a large base", i.e. with a base higher than the maximum number of classes in this case. You could do it in base-16 instead, where your two rules would come out `00d0` and `0100`. But you're right, and in fact the system you mention isn't in the specification. It's just the way some book authors/bloggers have used to make it comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

It's more like:

```
1) inline       (1.0.0.0)
2) id           (0.1.0.0)
3) class        (0.0.1.0)
4) html elments (0.0.0.1)
```

E.g. no matter how many class selectors you will provide, they will never go beyond the id.

According to your markup

```
.a1 .a2 .a3 .a4 .a5 .a6 .a7 .a8 .a9 .a10 .a11 .a12 .a13 {
    color : red;
}
#id1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

corresponding weights are:

```
0.0.13.0 <-- for the classes
0.1.0.0 <-- for the ID
```