# How to override CSS nth-child selector property from the HTML

Tags: html, css

Overriding background-color of the .gantt-row class below is easily done by adding a style attribute to the DIV:

```
<div style="background-color: blue" class="gantt-row">
```

Is it also possible to override the background-color of the gantt-row:nth-child selectors from within the markup?  Or is it necessary to use jQuery for this?

```
.gantt-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.gantt-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.gantt-row:nth-child(even) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

Comment: If you could consolidate your html / css into one functioning reproducible example using the same snippet editor you used to post the two parts separately it might provide a bit more context to visualize what you hope to achieve. However it seems like you could just use the `!important` flag with your other css classes to override others.

Comment: You should read up about [specificity weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Inline-style has the highest specificty weight and therefor should be avoided. It can only be overrruled with the `!important` proerty command: `background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS specificity: Why isn't CSS specificity weight of 10 or more class selectors greater than 1 id selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667685/css-specificity-why-isnt-css-specificity-weight-of-10-or-more-class-selectors)

Comment: My question is more a matter of how one targets the nth-child property from back in the markup.  Targeting the base class properties is easy, but not so the selector properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly affect the style of the nth-child element like that, but you can set CSS variables which can be picked up when styling a property.

In this snippet a parent container can be styled inline with a --bg variable setting and this can be picked up by the settings for the nth-child(even).

```css
.gantt-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.gantt-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

.gantt-row:nth-child(even) .gantt-row-name {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<div style="--bg: blue;">
  <div class="gantt-row">odd</div>
  <div class="gantt-row">even</div>
</div>
```

Note, it doesn't have to be a direct parent, any ancestor will do.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.  By using a CSS variable in this instance my Gantt chart is now working exactly as intended, with the ability to specify alternate row colours back in the markup.  Top answer!

Comment: @ChristopherDodunski click the check mark near the upvote/downvote buttons if this answered your question.

Comment: @Yong I tried but, alas, I don't have the prerequisite 15 reputation points.

Comment: Hi, I think you are allowed to accept an answer to your own question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20 but you need reputation to vote (which is different),

Comment: @AHaworth sorry, I confused up vote for the tick (as we call it in NZ).  Thanks again for your excellent solution, which I've now ticked as the preferred answer. 

Comment: Glad it worked - we nearly speak the same language (!) [from the UK].

Answer (score 0):

Please find below two solutions you can use.

- First is to set the css for the nth-child again, so that the previous css, the bottom css will override the initially set styling.
- Another way is to use [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) which will override the previous css, the advantage of this is that we need not be dependent on nth-child and just style the overrides using classes.

```css
.gantt-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(even) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
/*using nth selector to override your previous css*/
.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(2) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: red;
}
/*using specficality to override your previous css*/
.wrapper .gantt-row.test.test-test:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row.test.test-test:nth-child(2) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="gantt-row test test-test">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="https://www.marine.com">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="gantt-row test test-test">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="https://www.marine.com">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="gantt-row test test-test">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="https://www.marine.com">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Naren.  You've added an additional colour within the CSS, namely red.  Sorry, it's not clear to me how this would allow alternate row colours to be set to an arbitrary colour back in the HTML.  To any colour desired, not necessarily #F6F6F6 or red.

Comment: @ChristopherDodunski Seems like it needs JS, anyway no problem, all the best! Have you checked out this attribute? [bgColor](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/tags/att_body_bgcolor.asp.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="gantt-row check checker">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="https://www.marine.com">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="gantt-row check checker">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="https://www.marine.com">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="gantt-row check checker">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="https://www.marine.com">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

```
.gantt-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(even) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row:nth-child(2) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row.check.checker:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .gantt-row.check.checker:nth-child(2) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).